# Getting ts.createNodeArray is not a function error on compiling NestJS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs

Recently we migrated to node v19.7 from node v14 in our NestJS project, and doing so we updated all our packages in package.json.

But upon updating the same, now we are facing a strange error, and I am not able to figure out what might be causing it.

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "myproj",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "engines": {
        "npm": ">8.0.0 <=9.5.0",
        "node": "19.7.0"
      },
    "scripts": {
        "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
        "build": "nest build",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
        "start": "nest start",
        "start-watch": "nest start --watch",
        "start-debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts -f json -o eslint-report.json",
        "lint-report": "eslint . -f node_modules/eslint-detailed-reporter/lib/detailed.js -o eslint-report.html",
        "test": "jest --coverage",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
        "test:e2e": "jest --config ./tests/jest-e2e.json",
        "prettier-format": "prettier --config .prettierrc **/*.ts --write",
        "prepare": "cd .. && husky install connector/.husky"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/tasks": "^3.1.1",
        "@nestjs/axios": "2.0.0",
        "@nestjs/common": "^8.4.7",
        "@nestjs/config": "^2.3.1",
        "@nestjs/core": "^8.4.7",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.4.7",
        "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.1",
        "@nestjs/terminus": "^8.1.1",
        "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
        "circular-json": "^0.5.9",
        "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
        "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "eslint": "^8.37.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
        "eslint-detailed-reporter": "^0.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.7.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rimraf": "^4.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
        "swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.2",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nestjs/cli": "^8.2.8",
        "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
        "@nestjs/testing": "^8.4.7",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
        "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
        "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
        "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
        "jest": "^29.5.0",
        "lint-staged": "^13.2.0",
        "node-mocks-http": "^1.12.2",
        "prettier": "^2.8.7",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
        "supertest": "^6.3.3",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
        "typescript": "^5.0.3",
        "husky": "^8.0.3"
    },
    "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "json",
            "ts"
        ],
        "rootDir": ".",
        "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "**/*.(t|j)s"
        ],
        "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
            "dist"
        ],
        "testTimeout": 9000
    }
}
```

On running, npm run start-watch, I am getting this error: ts.createNodeArray is not a function

I have already tried with deleting the node_modules, package-lock.json files, also I tried with npm clean cache --force, but still this didn't helped to resolve this issue.

Comment: but you dont have start script in package.json

Comment: @choco sorry, I have updated the package.json code. somehow I copied it from my other repo. you can check now.

Comment: that's probably due to typescript v5, right? can you show us the whole error message

Comment: @MicaelLevi that's the whole error that I am getting. As soon as run, npm run start-watch, console shows this: 
Starting compilation in watch mode...
Error  ts.createNodeArray is not a function

and the compilation and execution stops there.
Also, I am not able to figure out whether the issue is with the typescript version or with any other package.

Comment: @ysdev Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just try and doing this

```
"ts-node": "~10.7.0",
"typescript": "~4.6.4"
```

Seems to work for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the version of Typescript. When looking at your logs, do you have issues with peer dependencies? If yes, you need to look at the package that is causing the problem and look at its peerDependencies. Make sure they're all compatible. Let us know if that works